# javascript not triggering in mvc

Tags: jquery, view, jscript

Following is my Jscript in one of View in my MVC 4 project.

but for some reason it is not triggering.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#purchasedate, #paymentdate, #datepickerNoModel").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

    $("#WBSlips").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDetails", "KapasPurchase")',
            data: { slips: $("#WBSlips").text() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#txtVehicleNo").val(data[0]);
                $("#txtFarmerId").val(data[1]);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: did you check browser console? Also, your code snippet is somewhat incomplete. Revise your question please because it is difficult to tell from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what you're actually doing in this code...

You attach a function to the `document.ready` handler to execute at that event:

```
$(function () {
  // code
});
```

And in that function you... attach a function to the `document.ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code
});
```

So that function will run *the next time* the document is ready.  Which never happens.

Simply remove one of your references to the `document.ready` handler:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#WBSlips").change(function () {
    // code
  });
});
</script>
```

Note also that of course the document is going to need a `#WBSlips` element at the time this executes in order to attach anything to its `change` handler.  I'm assuming that's the case here.

Comment: I changed my code as below. ' $("#WBSlips").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDetails", "KapasPurchase")',
                    data: { slips: $("#WBSlips").text() },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#txtVehicleNo").val(data[0]);
                        $("#txtFarmerId").val(data[1]);
                    }
                })
            });
 </script>' but still nothing is happening

Comment: @sirajahmed: Please post code updates in the question.  It's unreadable in comments.  Also be specific.  "Nothing is happening" doesn't really tell me much.  When you debug this, what *does* happen?  Does the code execute at all?  Is the target element found?

Comment: i guess target element is not found.

'code' <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.slipno, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Wquery), "- - - - Select - - - - ", new { id = "WBSlips" })</td>

Comment: @sirajahmed: In your previous comment it looks like you removed *both* `document.ready` handlers.  If that's the case then at the very least the code is going to have to be placed *after* the element on the page.  You can't attach a handler to an element that doesn't exist yet.  But you're going to have to examine your client-side code in the browser to confirm anything.  I can't debug this for you.

Comment: @Rohit416, I checked my Browser Console, which says " Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: I replaced my code as mentioned above and the code is able to reach the target element, Thank you.